# Setting up an ASP.NET MVC development enviornment with software from Dream Spark

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, development-environment

I need help figuring out what programs I need to setup a development enviornemnt on my new Windows 7 laptop. I have a LAMP background and I have only used ASP.NET once. The first time using ASP.NET I installed all the nessassary software along with Visual Studio Express with one click from asp.net.

This time around I qualify for free software from Dream Spark. I'm not sure what programs I need to download in order to get eveything up and running correctly.

These are the programs I think I need and are available from Dream Spark:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- Windows Server 2008R2 Standard
- SQL Server 2008R2 Developer

I have a few questions:

1. Would this be correct?
2. Am I missing anything?
3. Should I use the Windows Server 2008R2 Standard in this way or should I save this key for use in a production enviornment?

PS: Main effort here is to get more aquainted with ASP.NET programming web applications but I would also like to dabble in Windows desktop application programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, Windows Server 2008R2 Standard is not compulsory to install to use  Visual Studio 2010 Professional & SQL Server 2008R2 Developer,
you can install both in any os ( windows 7 too ).